# Formulas for $\pi$

Tags: pi

Given a formula for $\pi$ like:

$$4⋅\sum^\infty_{k=1}   \frac{(−1)^{k+1}}{2k−1}    =    4⋅(1−1/3+1/5−1/7+1/9−1/11…).$$

or some of the several others; how can you know that it holds true to any $k$? Couldn't it be that from a certain value upwards, the series start to diverge from $\pi$?

Comment: What does 'any $k$' mean in this context?

Comment: The series is convergent by Leibniz' criterion, hence it cannot diverge.

Comment: The OP means "How we do we know that the series converges to $\pi$ (and not just something very close to $\pi$)?" The answer is by proving it :P

Comment: What does "how can you know that it holds true to any $k$?" mean? The series on the LHS is a sum of infinitely many terms (in a specific order), adding one at a time. The more you add, the closer you get to the limit value, which is $\pi$.

Comment: I think what you need to understand is this: we always **prove** such formulas by showing that they are equivalent to a certain definition for $\pi$ (or any other constant). We are never satisfied with adding a finite number of terms and thinking 'well, this looks like $\pi$' :)

Comment: For example, if we say that $\pi$ is precisely the area of a cirlce with radius $1$, then we can **define** $\pi$ by the following integral: $$\pi=2 \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$ Then any alleged 'formula for $\pi$' will need to be checked against this definition. If we can somehow show that one follows from another, then we are set

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on where you want to start.

You can start with the definition of $\arctan x$, develop the series expansion for that, and then plug in $x=1$ to set the whole thing equal to $\pi/4$.  Or you can calculate it geometrically [the way Leibniz did](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Leibniz's_Formula_for_Pi).

Absent equating the series to some multiple of $\pi$ you can calculate two series that approach $\pi$ from above and below, and then squeeze out an expression for $\pi$ that way.

But the answer to your question is that often the series pops out from some expression which is already known to be a multiple of $\pi$.